# Nakayama's lemma's for projective modules over local rings.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $(R, m)$ be a local ring and $M$ a finitely generated projective $R$-module.

Let $n$ be the number of elements in a minimal generating set of $M$. Then by Nakayama's lemma $M/m M$ any minimal generating set of $M/ m M$ as an $R$-module must have at least $n$ elements.

It seems that this implies that $M/mM$ has dimension $n$ as a $R/mR$ module. Why is this?

Comment: The way I think about it, so that I can be checked too. First of all, M is not necessarily projective. Nakayama’s Lemma proves that you can lift a generating system in the quotient to a generating system of M. This gives the fact: consider a minimal generating set, pass it to the quotient, (it generates the vector space), refine it to obtain a basis of the vector space and lift it again by Nakayama’s Lemma. By minimality, you have the same system of generators, hence that must be the dimension of the basis. Works?

Comment: But why does it necessarily generate the vector space?

Comment: Nakayama only tells us that it generates the quotient as an $R$-module, not as an $R/mR$-module.